# В vs нету вкладки добавить ссылку

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Я программирую на маке в vs, и у меня нигде нету вкладки, чтобы добавить ссылку на библиотеку классов. В ютюбе смотрел, у всех все нормально. Попытался добавить эту вкладку, не помогло. И че делать?

Comment: У вас там на маке есть прав.кнопка мыши?

Comment: Да,есть.и куда надо кликать,прям на коде?

Comment: В `Solution Explorer` -> Название проекта-> на `Dependencies` прав.клик -> `Add Reference`

Comment: Спасиб,и в ютюбе,на гугле никто не мог это сделать